# Android appilcation force stops on hitting the button

Tags: java, android, xml

Im new to Android and having little problem while running this app. Whenever I hit the "ADD" button on my application it force stops. Please help me out. Im attaching my xml and java code along.

This is the error Im getting:

```
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe99d1f80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: akshay.com.myfirstapp, PID: 13085
              java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                  at akshay.com.myfirstapp.Addition$1.onClick(Addition.java:28)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Application terminated.
```

Here is my Addition.java

```
package akshay.com.myfirstapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Addition extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText2,editText3;
Button button;
TextView textView3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addition);

    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
            int j=Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
            int ans=i+j;
            textView3.setText(ans);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is my addition_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_addition"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="akshay.com.myfirstapp.Addition">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3" />

<TextView
    android:text="First Number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Second Number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Sum"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />
```

Comment: you are converting empty string to integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty string cannot be converted to an Integer, so you need to check that your EditTexts are not empty first.

And as pointed out by @csabapap, the `setText` method on your TextView should be passed a String.

Final code could look something like this:

```
if (editText2.getText().length() != 0 && editText3.getText().length() != 0) {
    int i=Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
    int j=Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
    int ans=i+j;
    textView3.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
}
```

You may also want to give your EditText variables meaningful names. It is very difficult to tell which one is which, and doing this will save you valuable debugging time later on.

Comment: If you pass an int to setText() if will looking for a resource id. You should use textView3.setText(String.valueOf(ans))